# How to transform a Serverless framework yaml to template of Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

is there a way to get the transformed Cloudformation template from a serverless framework yaml via the console, CLI, or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use serverless framework cli to build your stack a new folder get created (.serverless) with generated Cloudformation tamplates, try to run this CLI command:

```sh
sls package
```

or

```sh
serverless package
```

both works.

The Cloudformation templates will be in JSON.